# How can I restart my game when gameover

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a game for school in ActionScript 3.0 and am nearly done.
But I need to make it so it will restart the game once you are on the game-over screen and you then press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>.

If anyone knows a way to reset it or change certain values and then change them back again after <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> is pressed please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have some kind of `resetGame()` function that would reset the values you want to return to the initial state. Then you can call it by listening for a key press like so:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);

function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
        resetGame();
    }
}

function resetGame():void {

    // reset variables
    level = 1;
    lives = 3;

    // put any objects back in their initial place
    hero_mc.x = 0;        

    // call some function that starts the game over again
    startGame();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you contain all the game-play elements of a single instance of your game in one class, then simply deleting the old instance of that class, and creating a new one would effectively reset your game with little effort.

If you then wanted some things to carry on from one play to the next (eg. highscores), simply store them in a different class.

Essentially the class should only contain information for a single run of the game.

It's simple to implement and works well.